# Url ReWrite in IIS 10

Tags: angular, iis-10

I am working on Angular 7 project and project deploy on IIS 10 server.

This is my second internal project so i have deploy in sub application of my main project.

but after deploy project static images path not working so i want to change images path using URL reWrite concept.

Right now i have set static image path in some place like:

```
src='../../../assets/noimage.jpg'
```

But after deploy project i want image url like:

```
src='App/assets/noimage.jpg'
```

Please let me know if any Url re-write rule possible for change images path.

Comment: set image url like     `src='./assets/noimage.jpg'` it will work on both local and IIS server .

Answer (score 0):

I've got a few projects (Angular 8) deployed on Windows Server (IIS10) and when referencing static images I am only using this reference: `<img src="assets/company-logo.png" >`

Answer (score 0):

If you host the angular app at sub-application in iis then you just need to add the ./ in the path.

before:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
```

change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./runtime.js"></script>
```